# How to delete spesific row on table with javascript? with using document.createElement()

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```
function AddItemOnTable(){
      if(getCookie("no") == null){
          var no = 1;
      }else if(parseInt(getCookie("no")) > 0){
          var no = getCookie("no");
      }else{
          var no = 1;
      }

      var tableRef = 
      document.getElementById('whatToBuy').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
      var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);// Nambahin row di 
      tabel diurutan terakhir

      var cell_no  = newRow.insertCell(0);// Tambah row pada index yang ke 0
      var newText  = document.createTextNode(String(no));// Memberikan text
      cell_no.appendChild(newText);
      no = String(parseInt(no) + 1);
      document.cookie = "no="+no;

      var cell_btn  = newRow.insertCell(7);
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      input.type = "button";
      input.className = "button";
      input.value = "x";
      var index = parseInt(no-2);
      //alert(index);
      input.onclick = "DeleteRow(index)";
      cell_btn.appendChild(input);
}
function DeleteRow(no){
  document.getElementById("whatToBuy").deleteRow(no);
  alert("a");
}
```

at the : input.onclick = "DeleteRow(index)";

Why it wont calling the function of "Delete Row"?
Im sorry for my bad english, im new on web developing :D

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the posted code.

First: the `onclick` attribute of the button element needs to a function object.

(Setting `onclick="doSomething()"` can by used in HTML to set a click handler within the opening tag of an element but is only parsed by the HTML parser, and can't be used in pure JavaScript.)

Second: the `deleteRow` method uses the current zero based index of the row in the table, but is being passed a parameter that is intended to be a `no` value obtained from a cookie or original table position.

The solution suggested here is to use the same `DeleteRow` function for all rows, but to modify it to find the *current* row position of the button clicked:

```js
var no = 100; // testing
var table = document.getElementById("whatToBuy");

function addRows() { // testing
    for( var  i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        button.type = "button";
        button.textContent = "delete index " + no;
        button.onclick = DeleteRow;

        var row = document.createElement("TR");
        var cell = document.createElement("TD");
        cell.appendChild(button);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        table.appendChild( row);

        ++no;
    }
}

function DeleteRow() {
    // find row to delete;

    for( var row = this; row=row.parentNode;) {
        if( row.tagName == "TR") {
            break;
        }
    }
    var rows = table.querySelectorAll("TR");
    for( var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i) {
        if( rows[i] === row) {
            table.deleteRow( i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="whatToBuy">
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="addRows()">add some rows</button>
```

If there is a need to determine the `no` value of the row being removed, I would suggest setting and inspecting a [`data attribtue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*), such as `data-no`, on the row element.